# textscan with different format data

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a data which has two formats which I'm trying to scan using `textscan` in MATLAB

```
1,2,3,four,five,6
7,8,9,ten,eleven,12
```

and so on, followed by another bunch of data with format as below

```
1,2,three,4
5,6,seven,8
```

I'm trying to scan this data using

```
fid=fopen('data.txt');    
C=textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %s %s %f','delimiter',',');
D=textscan(fid,'%f %f %s %f','delimiter',',');
```

The whole data looks like

```
1,2,3,four,five,6
7,8,9,ten,eleven,12

1,2,three,4
5,6,seven,8
```

Different format data is separated by an empty line, the problem is `C` gets data from the second table too, up to 1,2 hence upsets the format of `D`

How can I stop `textscan` once I encounter an empty line?

Comment: by default, `textscan` stops when it meets a format error and returns everything it has done prior to the line. What you want is to read in everything and then filter by the 2 formats

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into matlab's readtable function. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html

I've used this function to read in files delimited by a comma that contained both text and numbers, where textscan was being difficult. This table can then be converted into a cell array or matrix for whatever processing you want to do with it.

Comment: readtable() returns only the last table i want to store all the tables!!